# How to convert fasta files (.fa) to gtf files for transcriptome assembly

Tags: bioinformatics

Hi i am doing transcriptome assembly, it seems that the fasta file does not match with the gtf file that is available and i downloaded in the database.
I was wondering if there is a way to get a.gtf file from .fa file.

I mean with the whole sequence can i make a gtf file.
Hope your response.

Comment: It appears as if you are moving in the wrong direction. A gff file would contain loci within your sequence file, in this case your fasta file. The details are unclear so its hard to say specifically what to do, but I will say it would make much more sense to convert a gff file into a fasta instead of the other way around. You can convert the gff to a bed file, using the first column, and the two coordinate columns. You can then convert that bed file to a fasta as described here: http://bedtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/tools/getfasta.html

Comment: Some useful information would include: 
What tools are you using for your transcriptome assembly? 
What did you use to generate the gft file? 
Is this gft for gene models? Exons? 
What did you use as input for these files?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure I'm missing some information in your question, but a quick search revealed that this does not appear to be readily achievable.

From [this post](https://www.biostars.org/p/13406/), "you can't strictly convert fasta to gff because fasta contains sequence information and gff contains location information."

Given the similarity between gff and gtf formats, it is unlikely that fasta to gtf is easily done.

*For future reference, you should provide a lot more information to help people answer your question:*

1. What have you done to try and answer it yourself?
2. Sample data (i.e. how do gtf and fasta formats compare) with some input and expected outputs.

It is also unclear why you selected unix and python tags for the question.  These are great tools to be certain, but in no way related to your question.